# L2TP VPN connection stuck "Connecting" on Windows 10

Tags: windows-10, vpn, windows-10-v1803, l2tp

On Windows 10 Pro build 17134, when I try to connect to an L2TP VPN connection, through the system tray network menu, it gets stuck "Connecting" and never connects:

[image]

However, when I connect the same VPN through the Settings app, it connects just fine in seconds:

[image]

Obviously, this is more cumbersome, so how can I get the VPN to connect through the systray menu?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I never manged to fix it on my old computer, but for what it's worth:

On my new computer, currently running Windows 10 1903 (build 18362.295), I *can* connect through the systray menu just fine.